# What is the correct way to add a navigation controller without interfering with the splash screen

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, splash-screen

I've been trying to make a basic app where there's a splash-screen for three seconds and then opens a page where there are buttons and each button leads to another page which should all contain a back button.

I can get both the navigation between pages and splash-screen working but only separately. I have to sacrifice "Is Initial View Controller" for one to have the other.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+3 )
    {
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextPage", sender: nil)
```

}

I tried linking the splash-screen to the navigation controller and setting the splash-screen as Initial View Controller. I also set the splash-screen as Initial View Controller

Comment: is there any activity on this question ? Still unable to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Select the ViewController you want to add a Navigation Controller to

2.Go to the menubar(where File,Edit are located) and click on "Editor"

3. Scroll down to "Embeded in"
4. Select "Navigation Controller"

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to a 'splash page' that you are referring to. You are talking about the launch screen. Generally speaking your xcode application project should have initialized with one already called LauchScreen.storyboard.

This storyboard is the 'splash page' that you see when an application is first launched and before it is fully loaded.

When your application finally launches and loads fully you should have your application loading onto your navigation controller that is set up in a different Storyboard.

[image]

Above is the root view controller which is also my navigation view controller.

Then you can set up other view controllers that you embed into this navigation controller. 
[image]

I simply added view controllers and from the 'main' view i have segued the buttons to each respective view controller with the 'show' segue.
and viola !

Hope this helps

--UDPATE---

[image]

to see what storyboard you are using as your launch screen select your project in the navigator, then select the target and select 'general' tab at the top. Scroll down to app icons and launch images.

Note: if you do not have any launchscreen.storyboard. you can create a fresh story board and name it 'launchscreen' (or splash screen if you like) then in the same section as described above you should be able to select the story board in the drop down menu.

NOTE: once your launchscreen.storyboard has finished launching and your application is going to launch fully.

*Using the same steps provided above* 
Under 'general tab' you should see 'deployment info' 
[image]

It is here you will see what storyboard will be launched.
Next to 'main interface' you can see that mine is Main (is called Main.storyboard)
Clicking the down arrow will allow you to select what story board you want to use for main interface.

Remember: your 'splash screen' is the launchscreen.storyboard that is defined in your target settings under 'general tab' and once that 'splash screen' is finished, the application will automatically load your main interface ( also defined in under 'general tab' in target settings ). 
There is no need for a segue between the 'splash screen' and your main storyboard.